# Problem rendering quick effect fluid animation

Tags: rendering, animation, effects

Please, try this:

Start Blender, select the cube, add quick effect (type: liquid).

Press space bar to run the animation. Up to here, it is ok for me. Now comes the problem.

Change to the render view then run again. This doesn't work for me, even if I change from Eevee to Cycles. Does it for you?

So, my question is: **How to render this animation?**

Comment: :-) you have to enable "Mesh" in properties like now you see only particles. Check some tutorials with mantaflow solved.

Comment: Hey @susu thank you for replying. I watched to toutube videos and read some tutorials, but didn't find any one with rendering. So I have no idea on how to do it :-/

Comment: Even with @susu comment, it was still not clear for me how to proceed. But hist tip of searching for tutorials with mantaflow solved, I got this link that helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fanm2P5ITCs

Comment: I did not comment, I edited the title of the question only the comment comes from @vklidu

Comment: Ow... my mistake. Tank you @vikidu for the comment and sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In case you arrive here looking for a simple answer without wanting to watch the youtube video. As @Brasil describes:

- press space to run the animation showing particles which will be quick.
- stop the animation and return to frame 1
- with the `Liquid Domain` object selected open the `Physics Properties` tab, scroll down and tick the `Mesh` check-box.
- step through the animation to the frame you want to render

EDIT: as @mins says below, if you change some of the flow parameters, such as the domain dimensions or any obstacles, after the first 'automatic' bake then the animation won't necessarily change. Some changes, like the the `Resolution Divisions` in the `Settings` section will force a cache rebuild.

To re-bake it you can switch the `Type` in the `Cache` section to `Modular`, return to frame 1 then switch back to `Replay` and re-run the animation to rebuild the cache.

Alternatively switch `Type` to `All` then click on the `Bake All` button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. It seems you also need to "bake" the domain object, first selecting a cache type `all` or `modular` to display [the bake button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYTdC.png) (which turns into a free button after being used).